# Android Emulator not rendering properly using Xamarin.forms, Unable to see the app I am developing on the Emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I just installed VS 22 with Xamarin.forms and I am trying to get some handle on mobile app development.

Now, when I start debugging using the emulator, I get this message:

> Your GPU driver information:
> GPU #1
> Make: 8086
> Model: Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
> Device ID: 0166
>
> Some users have experienced emulator issues with this driver version. As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer. Please, check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.

I have even gone ahead to update to the latest driver. The issue is still the same. I have been able to successfully connect my android 9 phone (which I put in developer mode) and the sample Xamarin app is displaying properly on the device.

So, how do I resolve this issue?

I am running Windows 10 Pro on Lenovo T430 having 16GB RAM.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xamarin Forms.  This is a problem with the Android emulator and your PC.  There are numerous existing posts about similar issues

Comment: Ok. Can you pls point me to a post offering a workable solution. Mine emulator doesn't freeze: only doesn't render well. I can't see the app I am developing but can see all other android icons and when I tap on them, they are working as they should.

Comment: Have you had this issue before? Have you checked the requirements for the Android emulator?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements